# Reformat text \r\n and set element value

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am trying to reformat a text which is coming from my MongoDB database containing `\r\n` to put the text on a new line.

Example text from DB:

> ```
> something something. \r\n Here i want to start on a new row.
> ```

So far I've managed to format the code and it looks OK in the console but I don't know how to set the display correctly because it shows the last value of the `forEach` iteration.

`index.html` ->

```
<ul class="dFraze">
<% service.description.forEach(function (description) { %>
<li class="data"><%= description.description_fraze %></li>
</ul>
```

`script.js` ->

```
let data = $('.data');
data.hide();

let descriptionFraze = $('.dFraze');

if (data.length > 0 ) {
    let str = data.text().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    let newData = str.split('<br />');

    newData.forEach((paragraph)=>{
        console.log(paragraph);
        descriptionFraze.append(descriptionFraze.html('<li>'+ paragraph + '</li> <br>'));
    });
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to hold up the data that I receive in the `forEach` and append a `\n` at the end which will display the text on a new line?

Comment: `descriptionFraze.append(descriptionFraze.html('<li>'+ paragraph + '</li> <br>'))` - that is nonsense in any case, you can not have a BR element as child of a list.

Comment: @CBroe I am trying all possilbe solutions that i cand come up with

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to put every single line of text into its own LI element? LI elements display in “lines” per default, so why would you want to insert a BR after each LI to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I am retriving multiple rows form the db and want to put each row on a separate <li>

Comment: I don’t see any DB stuff anywhere, but instead you seem to be reading the text content from the existing LI elements already ... what’s the logic behind that then? Why was this data not output in the desired form to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe - The data comes here : <li class="data"><%= description.description_fraze %></li> /// I did not display this here because is not formatted

Comment: So that is supposed to represent one single “record” from the database then? So you have multiple such LI already when your script starts? Still doesn’t explain why you would want to do this on DOM level ...